# How to translate conditional statement in i18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having a hard time providing I18n support for the statement below. How do I provide i18n for 'Update User' and 'Create New User'?

```
h1 = @user.persisted? ? 'Update User' : 'Create New User'
```

Comment: You can't put an `if` statement inside a translation; translations are just text substitutions. And I'd highly discourage trying to be "clever" by doing anything like: `"#{@user.persisted? ? t('.update') : t('.create_new')} #{t('.user')}"` ... Anything like that will almost certainly fail in other languages, which have different grammar rules. Just keep it simple. Leave the `if` statement alone, and move the text, as-is, into a translation.

Answer (score 4):

Normally you should just add `t('.what_you_need_to_translate')`, so in your case it will be

```
h1 = @user.persisted? ? t('.update_user') : t('.create_new_user')
```

Of course that's taking into consideration that you have the `'rails-i18n'` gem and that the mentioned translations are existing in the correct files.

Comment: You don't need to add any gems for `I18n` in Rails

Answer (score 2):

I know Hesham already answered but you can also do in below way

```
@user.new_record? ? t('.update_user') : t('.create_new_user')
```